# Get the 1st and Last array based on criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script

I have an array that looks like this.

```
[[2017-08-31,AA, 12:00 PM], 
 [2017-08-31,AA, 01:00 PM], 
 [2017-08-31,AA, 01:00 PM], 
 [2017-08-31,AA, 02:00 PM], 
 [2017-08-31,BB, 03:00 PM], 
 [2017-08-31,BB, 04:00 PM]]
```

and here is my code on how I sort it based on time.

```
 TITOArray.push([output_stddate,std_timein]);
    TITOArray.sort(function (a, b) {
      var time1 = a[2];
      var time2 = b[2];
      return new Date('1970/01/01 ' + time1) - new Date('1970/01/01 ' + time2);
    });
  }
```

How can I get the first and last array?

like this.

```
[[2017-08-31,AA, 12:00 PM], 
 [2017-08-31,AA, 02:00 PM], 
 [2017-08-31,BB, 03:00 PM], 
 [2017-08-31,BB, 04:00 PM]]
```

as long as the criteria in column 1 and column 2 are the same get 1st and last array.

I mean For every Column1 and Column 2 Group get the 1st and Last array

TYSM for help

Comment: Still the question is not so clear. Where is the first and last array? There are 4 arrays in the result which you have mentioned

Comment: I mean, lets say that Column 1 and Column 2 are groups and in that group how can I get the first and last array?

Comment: For every Column1 and Column 2 Group get the 1st and Last array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function firstandlast() 
{
  var tA=[['2017-08-31','AA','12:00 PM'],['2017-08-31','AA','01:00 PM'],['2017-08-31','AA','01:00 PM'],['2017-08-31','AA','02:00 PM'],['2017-08-31','BB','03:00 PM'],['2017-08-31','BB','04:00 PM']];
  var gA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<tA.length;i++)
  {
    if(i==0)
    {
      gA.push(tA[i]);
    }
    else
    {
      if(tA[i][1]!=last1)
      {
        gA.push(tA[i-1]);
        gA.push(tA[i]);
      }
    }
    var last1=tA[i][1];
  }
  if(gA.indexOf(tA[tA.length-1])==-1)
  {
    gA.push(tA[tA.length-1]);
  }
  Logger.log(gA);
}
```

Comment: Its working for me, does this code working in many rows even if the data is randomly arranged?

Comment: This code works fine I just need to add additional codes when, like sorting it by date and time before getting the 1st and last. TYSM for help sir :)

Comment: I do assume that all of the middle elements are sorted vertically.  It looks exactly like the rows of a spreadsheet.  So I assumed the sheet was sorted by column two.

Comment: Actually sir my target here is to Group them 1st by Column 2 then Sort them by Column 1  and Column 3 before removing the first in last row. Its like a multiple time in and time out but I will just get the 1st and last row dow based on Column 1 and 2

Comment: Do you think sir the code youve given satisfy this criteria?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var testData = [['2017-08-31','AA','12:00 PM'],
['2017-08-30','AA','01:00 PM'],
['2017-08-31','AA','01:00 PM'],
['2017-08-31','AA','02:00 PM'],
['2017-08-31','BB','03:00 PM'],
['2017-08-31','BB','04:00 PM']];
function treeishSort (multiArray) {
    var rootNode = {};
    multiArray.forEach(function(row) {
        pushNode(row[0], row[1], row[2]);
    });
    function pushNode(date, category, time) {
        var key = date + '\n' + category;

        if(rootNode[key] || (rootNode[key] = [])) {
            rootNode[key].push(time);
            if(rootNode[key].length > 1) { //if there are two item sort the array;
                rootNode[key].sort(function (time1, time2){
                    return new Date('1970/01/01 ' + time1) - new Date('1970/01/01 ' + time2)
                 });
            }
            if(rootNode[key].length > 2) { //if there are three items repalce the array with first and last
                rootNode[key] = [rootNode[key][0], rootNode[key][2]]; 
            }
        }
    }
    function getFirstLast(tree) {
        let temp = [];
        Object.keys(tree).forEach(function (key) {
            var date = key.split('\n')[0];
            var category = key.split('\n')[1];
            temp.push([date, category, tree[key][0]]);
            if(tree[key].length > 1) temp.push([date, category, tree[key][1]]); //there might be only item so this check
        })
        return temp;
    }
    return getFirstLast(rootNode);
}
console.log(treeishSort(testData));
```

edit 1:
i have converted into a function and pre es5

Comment: Sir what is `treeishSort`

Comment: Sir its not working for me atleast a `function()` javascript